# Setting up Symfony2 to work with apache + php-fpm

Tags: apache, symfony, config, php

How does one set up Symfony2 to work on Apache (Apache 2.4) combined with php-fpm?

The aim is to get rid of the .htaccess files and move everything into the apache config.

Without worrying about PHP-FPM, the config looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysymfonyproject.com
  ServerAlias www.mysymfonyproject.com
  ErrorLog  /path/to/logs/mysymfonyproject_error.log
  CustomLog /path/to/logs/mysymfonyproject_access.log combined

  DocumentRoot "/path/to/sites/mysymfonyproject/web"
  <Directory "/path/to/sites/mysymfonyproject/web">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    ## Start directives copied from standard Sf .htaccess
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.php

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    ## End directives copied from standard Sf .htaccess
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This thread is for me to post my own findings (and perhaps be corrected if I got it wrong!).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to just use ProxyPassMatch to make this work.  By using this method, your rewrite rules in .htaccess don't need to be changed.

Here is my Apache2 vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.51:80>                                                     
ServerName grae.labs.brainglove.com                                             
ServerAlias www.grae.labs.brainglove.com                                        

DocumentRoot /srv/symfony2/2.4.4/grae/web                                       
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php                                                      

ProxyPassMatch  ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/srv/symfony2/2.4.4/grae/web/$1                                                                             

<Directory /srv/symfony2/2.4.4/grae/web>                                        
    AllowOverride All                                                           
    Options FollowSymLinks                                                      
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/grae.labs.brainglove.com_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/grae.labs.brainglove.com_access.log combined
```

The only line you need to add is the ProxyPassMatch.  Everything else stays the same.

Don't forget to change the IP address and path to your symfony2 web directory.

Comment: I find with this configuration that all in page URLs and redirects include the complete folder path to the web folder.  So from your example, a redirect to app_dev.php would take you to www.grae.labs.brainglove.com/srv/symfony2/2.4.4/grae/web/app_dev.php, instead of www.grae.labs.brainglove.com/app_dev.php.  Is there something else I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

To pass a request through to PHPFPM, the suggested RewriteRule was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://uds=%2fpath%2fto%2fwww.sock/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [P,END]
```

Here's what I ended up. It seems to be working so far, but perhaps there's a better way?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysymfonyproject.com
  ServerAlias www.mysymfonyproject.com
  ErrorLog  /path/to/logs/mysymfonyproject_error.log
  CustomLog /path/to/logs/mysymfonyproject_access.log combined

  DocumentRoot "/path/to/sites/mysymfonyproject/web"
  <Directory "/path/to/sites/mysymfonyproject/web">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    ## Start directives copied from standard Sf .htaccess
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.php
        # Need to add the phpfpm call here so that php files (including app_dev.php) are passed to FPM
        RewriteRule ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://uds=%2fpath%2to%2fwww.sock/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [P,END]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

        # The main phpfpm call is added at the end to pass php requests through to FPM
        RewriteRule ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://uds=%2fpath%2to%2fwww.sock/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [P,END]
    </IfModule>
    ## End directives copied from standard Sf .htaccess
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```